# Div isn't always centred

Tags: css

I have centred everything on the website fine, its just when I resize the window too small so the div is bigger than the window, the div is stuck to the left of the screen, but I want the div to *always* be centred. If you don't get what I mean you can view the website [here](http://henrynorthen.com/).
The 'div' I'm mainly talking about is the blue 'stroke' just above the footer.

**I'm viewing this in Google Chrome**

Comment: I would recommend setting a `min-width` on `.page`

Comment: That has fixed half of it! I just need it to centre when the browser window is small

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fixed width with absolute positioning will do it.

```
.page {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 75px 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -500px;
    left: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Site.css line 10